# Generic greatest N per group query is too slow

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

The following query takes 18 minutes to complete. How can I optimize it to execute faster?

Basically, my query for every citizen joins row from `citizens_static` and `citizens_dynamic` table where `update_id_to` column is highest.

```
INSERT INTO latest_tmp (...)

SELECT cs1.*, cd1.*
FROM citizens c

JOIN citizens_static  cs1 ON c.id = cs1.citizen_id
JOIN citizens_dynamic cd1 ON c.id = cd1.citizen_id

JOIN (
    SELECT citizen_id, MAX(update_id_to) AS update_id_to
    FROM citizens_static
    GROUP BY citizen_id
) AS cs2 ON c.id = cs2.citizen_id AND cs1.update_id_to = cs2.update_id_to

JOIN (
    SELECT citizen_id, MAX(update_id_to) AS update_id_to
    FROM citizens_dynamic
    GROUP BY citizen_id
) cd2 ON c.id = cd2.citizen_id AND cd1.update_id_to = cd2.update_id_to;
```

`latest_tmp` table is MyISAM table with indexes disabled during import. Disabling them improved execution time from 20 minutes to 18 minutes, so it's not the biggest problem.

I also benchmarked `LEFT JOIN` approach with `WHERE t2.column IS NULL`. It takes several hours comparing to `INNER JOIN` approach which I'm using.

Explain query output below. It seems to be using indexes.
[image: explain]

`citizens_dynamic` and `citizens_static` have primary key on `citizen_id,update_id_to` and secondary key named "id" on `update_id_to,citizen_id` columns.

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain, in English, what you want?

Then see [Groupwise Max](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max#top_n_in_each_group)  And edit the following as needed:

```
SELECT
        province, n, city, population
    FROM
      ( SELECT  @prev := '', @n := 0 ) init
    JOIN
      ( SELECT  @n := if(province != @prev, 1, @n + 1) AS n,
                @prev := province,
                province, city, population
            FROM  Canada
            ORDER BY
                province,
                population DESC
      ) x
    WHERE  n <= 3
    ORDER BY  province, n;
```

Regardless of the ASC/DESC on the inner ORDER BY, there will be a full table scan and a 'filesort'.

Comment: Wouldn't your answer be faster if there was directional index on `[province ASC, population DESC]`? I know that MySQL doesn't allow to have such indexes, but with additional column `population_negative` it should be possible. My problem is that uncorrelated subquery is pretty fast (7M output rows, about 40M input rows), but not fast enough.

Comment: Ah, that is probably a partial optimization.  See bolds in edit.

Comment: No, since all rows need to be scanned, it is more efficient to do a full table scan, then a filesort.

Comment: The total 'effort' is about 3N, where N is the number of rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to be able to predict if this will run any better, but I would suggest to give this a try:

```
SELECT cs1.*, cd1.*
FROM citizens c

JOIN citizens_static  cs1 ON c.id = cs1.citizen_id
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                   FROM citizens_static cs2
                  WHERE cs2.citizen_id = cs1.citizen_id
                    AND cs2.update_id > cs1.update_id )

JOIN citizens_dynamic cd1 ON c.id = cd1.citizen_id
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                   FROM citizens_dynamic cd2
                  WHERE cd2.citizen_id = cd1.citizen_id
                    AND cd2.update_id > cd1.update_id )
```

PS: Please comment the running time (if it returns within the hour =), that way I might learn (not) to propose this construction in the future again.

Comment: 15s with LIMIT 10k, 38s with LIMIT 50k, 62s with LIMIT 100k. When I turned limits off it wouldn't complete in 30 minutes, so I guess it would take much, much longer than my solution.

Comment: OK, thanks for trying. That's not an option then. Another something learned =)
Just thinking aloud: assuming `update_id` is **guaranteed** to be perfectly sequential you could replace `AND c*2.update_id > c*1.update_id` with `AND c*2.update_id = c*1.update_id + 1` but that would screw up the results when there would be a 'hole' in the update_id's. Worth a try just for the fun of it, but in reality it's probably an accident waiting to happen.